# Tensorflow Word Embedding runs too slow on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding

EDIT: I can provide some rudimentary run times now:

```
next epoch:      0.5456549558716741 ('time point 0')
next epoch:    892.5030143482156    (~14:30min)
next epoch:   1757.6139726727963    (~14:30min)
Time elapsed: 2622.23 seconds       (~14min, total of 44min)
```

These times are with a `vocab_size` of only 5000 compared to the actual corpus size of 13k...

---

I'm working on a word embedding task in Tensorflow that works with the King James bible as corpus, so it's got a decent size of 13000 something unique words.

On my machine (GTX 970), I'm not even getting a print-out of reaching another epoch whereas on the CPU of a friend of mine, the process finished within a few minutes.

Could someone shed some light on this mystery?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from book_helper import Book
from collections import Counter
from math import sqrt
import random as rnd
import time

%matplotlib notebook

book = Book('./pg10.txt')
vocab_size = len(Counter(book._book_text)) # 13079
book.create_dictionaries(vocab_size)

samples = [x for x in rnd.sample(book._book_text, 10) if x.isalpha()]
print('Sample words:\t' + ', '.join(samples))
print('Words2ids:\t' + ', '.join([str(book.words2ids(samples))]))
print('Ids2words:\t' +  ', '.join(book.ids2words(book.words2ids(samples))))

# hyperparameters
batch_size = 128
epochs = 3
lrate = 1
embedding_size = 64
skip_window = 2
noise_samples = 64

X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size], "Input_Placeholder")
desired = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, 1], "DesiredOutput_Placeholder")

with tf.variable_scope("embeddings"):
    # create word embedding
    ru_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0)
    embeddings = tf.get_variable("embedding", 
                                 [vocab_size, embedding_size],
                                 initializer=ru_init)
    # retrieve word ids from embedding
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, X)

with tf.variable_scope("output_layer"):
    weights1 = tf.get_variable("weights", 
                               [vocab_size, embedding_size], 
                               initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(1 / sqrt(embedding_size)))
    biases1 = tf.get_variable("bias", initializer=tf.zeros([vocab_size]))

drive = tf.matmul(embed, tf.transpose(weights1)) + biases1
context = tf.nn.softmax(drive)
tf.summary.histogram("drive", drive)

with tf.variable_scope("nce_loss"):
    nce_weights = tf.get_variable("weights",
                                  [vocab_size, embedding_size],
                                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(1 / sqrt(embedding_size)))
    nce_bias = tf.get_variable("bias", initializer=tf.zeros([vocab_size]))

nce_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(weights= nce_weights,
                                        biases= nce_bias,
                                        labels= desired,
                                        inputs= embed,
                                        num_sampled= noise_samples,
                                        num_classes= vocab_size))

tf.summary.scalar("nce_loss", nce_loss)

training_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lrate).minimize(nce_loss)

merged_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()

train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./summaries/train", tf.get_default_graph())

with tf.Session() as session:
    start_time = time.clock()
    step = 0
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for _epoch in range(epochs):
        print("next epoch: " + str(time.clock() - start_time))
        for targets, concepts in book.get_training_batch(batch_size, skip_window):
            summaries, _ = session.run([merged_summaries, training_step], feed_dict = {X: targets, desired: concepts})
            train_writer.add_summary(summaries, step)
            step += 1

    duration = time.clock() - start_time
    print("Time elapsed: {0:.2f} seconds".format(duration))
```

Comment: do you have sure that your net is running on GPU?

Comment: Yep, just confirmed. It's running on GPU, Cuda and Cudnn are installed correctly, I have some ~500mb dedicated GPU memory left.

Comment: You can try to [profile](https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d) your net. See the time gaps between computation, it could say more about your problem to you

Comment: I'm going to look into that. The net just finished running, I provided some rough epoch times for further detail.

Comment: Run `nvidia-smi` while training, what what's your GPU usage at? 100%? 10%?